# Solving an augmented coefficient matrix so there are infinitely solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to figure out this math problem.

For what values $a,b$ does the linear system have infinitely many solutions?

This is the matrix

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-2&3&-4\\
      2&1&1&2\\
      1&a&2&-b
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I know the solution. $a = -1$ and $b = 2,$ but this is my problem. In the solutions it is written like this: $a=-1, b=2, x=t[-1\ 1\ 1]^{T}+[0\ 2\ 0]^{T}$.

I don't understand the solution as it is given; can somebody please explain it to me?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: $x$ is the solution to the linear system, with $t$ - arbitrary real number.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy so x can be x1, x2 or x3

Comment: @depecheSoul Yes, $x$ is a $3\times 1$ vector in the solution you have.  $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ where $x_1 = -t;\, x_2 = t+2;\; x_3 = t$.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for the quick answer. Can you tell me where did the t "pop out" from??? I mean I have a and b. When should I place t in the equation or better in te matrix???

Comment: $t$ is simply representing the value of $x_3$. Solving the row reduced matrix, with the last row all zeros, (assuming a = -1, b= 2), that means the solution for $x_3$ can be any real value whatsoever. So $x_3 = t$ is simply the "representative" which can be any real value. Then, solutions for $x_1 = -x_3 = -t$, $x_2= x_3 + 2 = t + 2$ are written in terms of $x_3 = t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Gaussian elimination, we arrive at

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&-1&2\\
0&0&a+1&-b-2a\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As you know, when $a = -1$ and $b=2$, the linear system of equations represented by the matrix above will have infinitely many solutions.

So assuming $a = -1,\;b = 2$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&-1&2\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $0x_3 = 0$ is true *for all real values $x_3$, we use $x_3 = t$ with $t\in \mathbb R$ to denote this.

Then we solve for $x_2$ using our matrix: $x_2 - x_3  = 2 \iff x_2 = x_3 + 2 = t + 2$.

Solving for $x_1$ using our matrix, we have $x_1 + x_3 = 0 \iff x_1 = -x_3 = -t$.

This gives us the (infinite number of) solutions of the form$$x = \begin{bmatrix} -t\\ t+2\\ t \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t \\ t \\  t\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = t \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad t \in \mathbb R$$